# How can I check if my SQL update has gone through?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Here is my prepared statement

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET :property=:value WHERE `id`=:id");
 $stmt->execute([':property' => $property, ':value' => $value]);
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

How can I quickly verify that the query has gone through successfully?

I was thinking maybe an if() around the execute part?

Comment: You can try an `if()` on the query itself

Comment: you mean around the first line? @LoganWayne

Comment: you can try `$stmt->rowCount` to check the amount of updated rows after the execute.

Comment: oh ok I'll try that, thanks @PhiterFernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
   echo 'SUCCESS';
}else{
   echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is test the returned `$stmt` like this.

Remember both the prepare and the execute can fail and should be checked

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET :property=:value WHERE `id`=:id");
if ( $stmt == false ) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
    exit;
}
$stmt->execute([':property' => $property, ':value' => $value]);
if ( $stmt == false ) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
    exit;
}
```

**This query will definitely fail**

> Now I look closer, you have a huge syntax error in the query. You cannot parameterise column or table names.
>
> You also pave 3 parameters and only 2 values

Comment: I realized that, I can't parameterise any column names, so big switch statement it is xD, thanks